# CSS Hover not full height or width of Nav

Tags: css, hover, nav

I'm trying to fill my Nav with the links shown, however, there's 2 things wrong with the a:hover.

One, it doesn't seem to be completely centered, even when I removed the top and bottom padding, which effects the height of the hover as it overflows it outside the nav element.

Two, the hover doesn't fill the height of the link element inside the Nav (I want it to fill the enitirety of the Nav height as aforementioned). I can edit the left and right margins, which reflects each time I save the css file, but aside from that is keeps overflowing over the top of  when I add top padding.

As far as the left-right padding, I can keep it from overflowing outside the element on the left side but can't get the right - do I need to adjust the max-width of the nav element? Can I use percentage for padding?

[My Result - in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvTSQ.jpg)

```
        nav
    {
        background: #c9cec8; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9cec8 1%, #babfb3 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9cec8 1%,#babfb3 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c9cec8 1%,#babfb3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        margin: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: 45px;
    }

nav a
{
    padding: 0px 20px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ECF0F1;
    background: #c9cec8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9cec8 1%, #babfb3 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9cec8 1%,#babfb3 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c9cec8 1%,#babfb3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}

    nav a:hover
    { 
        color: #34495E;
        background: #95a5a6; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #95a5a6 0%, #abb7b7 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #95a5a6 0%,#abb7b7 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #95a5a6 0%,#abb7b7 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    }
```

[End Result after CSS Edit help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHPMG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  should use ul  and this full cod for you with what you asked

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>

nav{
  background: #c9cec8; /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9cec8 1%, #babfb3 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9cec8 1%,#babfb3 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c9cec8 1%,#babfb3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
      margin: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 35%;
      height:55px;

}
.inline-list{
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

a{
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ECF0F1;}
  li a:hover
  {

      color: #34495E;
      background: #95a5a6; /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #95a5a6 0%, #abb7b7 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #95a5a6 0%,#abb7b7 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #95a5a6 0%,#abb7b7 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  }



  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <nav>
  <ul class="inline-list">
  <li>
   <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Team</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="#">Files</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="#">Forum</a>
  </li>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it works as it worked perfect in JSFiddle, but on my local end the Nav background gradient isn't there, and the styling for the section and content went away. Uploaded image into original post

Answer (score 0):

you could  give the link a height and width

```
nav a{

height:45px;

width:60px; or any width you want 

}
```

Comment: Hasn't changed anything, I even removed padding/margin, not sure what the deal is.

Comment: <nav>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Team</a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Files</a>
<a href="#">Forum</a>
</nav>

Just a straight up simple <nav>, haven't done anything fancy with HTML yet. Also thank you for your time.